# Ruby is unable to connect to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Frnds i have edited the database.yml as below for my postgresql db and downloaded pg gem and relating libraries.I serached it in the google and edited in that way.. but after running the server it shows the below error in the terminal window....... please help me in this...

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my db name
  username:  user name
  password: password
  host: host name

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db_pchamara
  database: my db name
  username:  user name
  password: password
  host: host name
  pool: 5


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my db name
  username:  user name
  password: password
  host: host name
  pool: 5
```

**but if i run the command 'rails server' in terminal it shows the following error.**

```
Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-05 18:10:51 +0530

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__189673354__call__558944823__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.3ms)
```

Comment: Try connecting to DB with psql: `psql -h 'localhost' --username 'user_name' 'database_name'`. If it works, the problem is on RoR and not on PostgreSQL

Comment: yeah .. that command works fine yaar.. its running in terminal console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup the gem 'pg' in your Gemfile?

Check your Gemfile, make sure that you commented (or deleted) the gem sqlite, and make sure that you have the gem pg listed

```
gem 'pg'
```

after that, run the bundle command (that will setup the libraries that your application will load before it starts):

```
bundle
```

Check the file Gemfile.lock, make sure that the gem pg is listed there.

Once you are done with all of that, make sure that you actually create the database in your postgresql server:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

And just in case, run any pending migration

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: sir if i run the command bundle it is not listing the postgres gem.. i tried for 'bundle show postgres'.. but no use

Comment: You don't need the "postgres" gem, you need the "pg" gem. Do you have the gem "pg" on your Gemfile as I wrote on my answer? If you do, when you run the command "bundle", you should see something like "Using pg (0.14.1)", and just to make sure that you have the gem, the file generated by bundle is called "Gemfile.lock" where you can see all the gems that your application depends on. So you can run "grep pg Gemfile.lock" and you should see the pg gem, if its not there, then something wrong is going on with your Gemfile, follow my instructions and try again. Thx

Comment: Sir i tried to install the pg gem by using 'gem install pg'. it runs and it shows the gem was successfully installed and ri doc also created.. but when i run bundle it is not showing there and one more thing initially i uninstalled sqlite3 gem but when i run the bundle the sqlite3 gem automatically gets installed... how to come with this sir???

Comment: can you update your answer and pastle the content of your Gemfile ? Just in case, delete Gemfile.lock and run bundle one more time

Comment: sir i have updated my problem.. Our required pg gem  file was installed...it shows in the bundle list..

Comment: Coming to the database i have already data in my database and i have done a project on java by using the same data.. now also i have to use the same data.. Then do i need to again create the database???

Comment: No, if the database is already there, you don't need to create it. However, you will need to write some configuration in the tables unless they follow the rails conventions.
In example, for the User model, rails use the table users, but if your table is named user by java already, you should write a line of code in your model like
set_table_name "user"
good luck with your project.

Comment: but if i try to connect through ruby programs to postgres db, then it brings the data.. But if i try the same thing with ruby then it wont works...........

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, my `database.yml` is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: kenyu_dev
  pool: 5
  username: kenyu
  password: super_secret_pass
  host: localhost
```

Also, did you create the user and gave him the right privileges? Try logging in as the user with `psql`

Comment: i am the super user of database.. i can logging in to postgres through psql command... butis shows the same error